# MergeSort only works with power of 2 array lengths

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, array-merge

I'm trying to do a MergeSort algorithm in c, and it doesn't exactly work, when i try small arrays ( lengh < 4) it works juste fine, but when it goes above 4, it only works with power of 2 length values.
For example if i have an array lenght of 8,16,32,64 the display will be a correct sorted array, but if it's not such values, it will display most of the array sorted, except for a few values which will be replaced by negative ones or so.

```
void merge(int t[], int l, int mid, int h)
{

    int left = mid - l + 1;
    int right = h - mid;
    int arr1[right];
    int arr2[left];

    for (int i = 0; i < right; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = t[mid + i + 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = t[l + i];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = l;

    while (i < left && j < right)
    {
        if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j])
        {
            t[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            t[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (j < right)
    {
        t[k] = arr2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    while (i < left)
    {
        t[k] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
}
void mergesort(int t[], int l, int h)
{

    if (l < h)
    {
        int mid = (l + h) / 2;
        mergesort(t, l, mid);
        mergesort(t, mid + 1, h);
        merge(t, l, mid, h);
    }
}
```

and here's how i make the call :

```
    mergesort(c, 0, len - 1);
```

Any idea on how to make it work corectly ?

I tried multiple tries, and it's always the same result

Comment: Step through the code with a so-called debugger. Try to find a video tutorial or something like that to get an introduction. Also, make sure you have unit tests for your code.

Comment: lobin_rock, best to post a complete compilie-able version that does not work.

Comment: Corner case: `(l + h) / 2` may overflow.  `(h-l) / 2 + l` does not.

Comment: lobin_rock Consider `mergesort(int t[], 0, 1)`, code attempts an array size of 0 leading to UB.

Comment: Your merge function mixes up the bounds of the two subarrays.  That won't matter when the original array has power-of-two size, because then each pair of subarrays will have matching size, but otherwise it will produce array overruns as well as plain incorrect behavior.

Comment: Building on John's answer, you'll find naming your mnemonics in accordance with the relationship to each other will help immensely in keeping things straight. Rather than `right` and `left`, as the sizes of `arr1` and `arr2`, had you used something as simple as `n1` and `n2` you probably would have caught your mistake. Unrelated, done correctly the high-side finishing copy (the loops after the primary while)  is not needed in a merge algorithm. those values are already in the target array in the right place. Only if the high side finishes *first* do you need the low side to finish.

Answer (score 3):

This ...

> it only works with power of 2 length values

... is a clue that the problem is related to merging subarrays of different sizes, because power-of-two array lengths are the (only) cases where that is never required.  And in fact, we see exactly such errors.

Given ...

> ```
>     int arr1[right];
>     int arr2[left];
> ```

... consider this ...

> ```
>     while (i < left && j < right)
>     {
>         if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j])
> ```

[...]

> ```
>             t[k] = arr1[i];
> ```

[ ...]

> ```
>             t[k] = arr2[j];
> ```

The bound of `arr1` is `right`, but you are accessing elements 0 - `left`.  The bound of `arr2` is `left`, but you are accessing elements 0 - `right`.

There are similar errors in the subsequent loops.